# Align label with button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

It's easier to explain what I need with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZrYG/1/

As you can see, when the output screen is fully extended, the sign in button is placed on the line under the label. I'm trying to get it so that the checkbox is left aligned and the button is right aligned on the same line. What's wrong with my css?

For prosperity:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span3">
      <form class="signin" method="POST">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
         <label class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" name="form[remember]" /> Remember me
         </label>
         <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mZrYG/7/embedded/result/)***

Hi now used to `display:inline-block` in your **label**

as like this

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The left-most element should be written first, so I have rearranged it as 
1. checkbox/Remember me
2. input boxes
3. Sign In

You also have to make sure the widths of all the boxes add to less than span12, so I have added span classes inside each of the 1/2/3 items above.

```
  <form class="signin" method="POST">
      <label class="checkbox span2">
     <input type="checkbox" name="form[remember]" /> Remember me
     </label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" class="span3"/>
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="span3"/>
      <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​

So the boxes above are now on the same line but you will have to play around with the "line-height" parameter in each of your css classes (ie checkbox and the 2 inputs) to make sure they're aligned completely straight.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this `float:left;` to input, label, button

or add class `fleft`

```
.fleft{
   float:left;
}
```

or if you want only this

> [image]

than try

```
<label style="float:left;" class="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[remember]" /> Remember me 
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</label>
```

Option 2:

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[remember]" /> Remember me 
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</label>
```